# Ho to convert pdf to image using ABCpdf?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, abcpdf

I am trying to convert an uploaded pdf (byte array) to an image using C# in my ASP.NET MVC application. My app is already using ABCpdf package, but I am having hard time finding code example on how to do such conversion using the package. Can anyone advise? Thanks in advance!

Here is my code. I currently get "Parameter not valid" error on the last statement.

```
HttpPostedFileBase Attachments;
byte[] PdfAttachmentData;

using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(Attachments.InputStream))
      {
          PdfAttachmentData= binaryReader.ReadBytes(Attachments.ContentLength);
      }
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(PdfAttachmentData))
      {
          Image myImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am unfamiliar with the library, but is `Doc.Rendering.Save(pathToPng)` what you're looking for?

Example in the [official documentation](https://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/default.htm), in Examples -> PDF Rendering Example.

**EDIT :**

Solution by OP :

```
Doc doc = new Doc(); 
doc.Read(ms); doc.Rendering.DotsPerInch = 72; 
for (int i = 1; i <= 1; i++) 
{ 
    doc.PageNumber = i;
    doc.Rect.String = doc.CropBox.String; 
    bitmap = doc.Rendering.GetBitmap(); 
}
```

Comment: I am not really trying to save. only convert.

Comment: @TomS I see. Then you might be looking for `Doc.Rendering.GetBitmap()` or `Doc.Rendering.GetMemory()` .

Comment: I got it resolved with the following code (not sure how to add it as an answer as they question has been closed by admins.

     Doc doc = new Doc();
     doc.Read(ms);
     doc.Rendering.DotsPerInch = 72;
     for (int i = 1; i <= 1; i++)
         {
             doc.PageNumber = i;
             doc.Rect.String = doc.CropBox.String;
             bitmap = doc.Rendering.GetBitmap();
    }

Comment: I'll edit in your solution in with appropriate formatting.